# Real time use case to use cts:after-query-timestamp

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I want to understand more about `cts:after-query-timestamp` and real-time use-case/scenario to use this cts function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cts:after-query-timestamp()` function is used to build a query to be used as the query criteria for [`cts:after-query()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:after-query), which is used to find documents/fragments committed after a specified timestamp.

For instance, if you want to find all of the documents that were inserted/updated within the last hour:

```
cts:uris("", (), 
  cts:after-query(xdmp:wallclock-to-timestamp(fn:current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration("PT1H")))
)
```